# How to get rid of devise current password requirement when editing a user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I've followed the instructions here:

http://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to-edit-user-form-without-current-password

But it seems to ignore that and still validate and require current password.

In fact, I can do whatever I want to app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb including putting tonnes of syntax errors in, and it still asks for the current password to be present.

What am I missing?

Comment: updating devise wiki page -> https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to quess, as you pasted no code, but it looks like you need to point devise to a different controller:

```
devise_for :user, :controllers => { :sessions => "..." }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip!I got it working by doing two things, first in routes.rb:

    devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }

and secondly, after adding the above, I had to copy my devise/registrations views out to just views/registrations.